# Having difficulty with Summation

Tags: probability, limits, summation

How would I compute:

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 - n} \cdot n$$

Hints or step by step process would be the most helpful.

Comment: Is the expression $(1 / (n^2 - n)) \cdot n$ correct? It looks a little off.

Comment: This is same as the harmonic series which diverges... You sure the question is correct?

Comment: I believe so. What exactly seems to be off about it? It's supposed to be an expected value.

Comment: @John Multiplying by $n$ at the end like that seemed strange, and I was afraid that I had edited the expression too hastily. Given that the sum turned out to be the harmonic series, it doesn't seem to be off at all.

Answer (score 5):

$$\sum_{n\geq 2} n/(n^2-n)=\sum_{n\geq 2} n/(n(n-1))=\sum_{n\geq 2} 1/(n-1)=1+1/2+1/3+...=\infty$$ is divergent harmonic series

Comment: How would I deal with the 2?

Comment: @John You could make the substitution $m = n - 1$.

Comment: Why is the final answer infinity? Eventually $\frac1{large number}$ becomes very close to 0. My calculator (casio fx-570 es plus) calculated $S_{999} = 7.48$ and then $S_{9999} = 9.79$.

Comment: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)